# Show that this is not true: $\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle^2=\vec{u}^2\cdot\vec{v}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that the "calculation rule" for the following scalar product is
>   wrong: 
>   $$\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle^2=\vec{u}^2\cdot\vec{v}^2$$

I'm not sure if I did it correctly?

Let $\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
u_2\\ 
u_3
\end{pmatrix},
\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\ 
v_2\\ 
v_3
\end{pmatrix}$

Then
$$\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle^2=\vec{u}^2\cdot\vec{v}^2 \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\left[\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
u_2\\ 
u_3
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\ 
v_2\\ 
v_3
\end{pmatrix}\right]^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\ 
u_2\\ 
u_3
\end{pmatrix}^2
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\ 
v_2\\ 
v_3
\end{pmatrix}^2$$

And at tjos point, I realized that you cannot square $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ because multiplication of $3 \times 1$ matrix with $3 \times 1$ doesn't work due to invalid size?

Is that reason enough to say that $\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle^2\neq\vec{u}^2\cdot\vec{v}^2$ ?

I'm really not sure about that and also about the correct notation. Or maybe you can do this a little more easy?

Comment: Take two orthogonal vectors

Comment: Yes, $\vec{u}^2$ is not a meaningful quantity for a general vector.

Comment: The people who are saying "take two orthogonal vectors" might be trying to disprove the related statement $\langle u,v\rangle^2 = \|u\|^2 \cdot \|v\|^2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov the notation $\vec u ^2$ means $\|\vec u\|^2$, that's a definition.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier It's one definition, which is new to me. It seems incompatible with the definition of a square of a matrix. Regardless, the real question is: is it the definition that's intended to be used in this question?

Comment: @MishaLavrov The question then is what else could it mean?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier The answer kathelk gives, that the statement is false in more than one dimension because $\vec u^2$ is undefined, since you can't multiply two $n \times 1$ matrices when $n>1$, seems plausible to me.

Comment: The notation of a square a vector to mean the dot product of a vector with itself is often used, although in my experience it’s much more used in physics than mathematics.

Comment: Problem with writing $\vec{u}^2$ is then you get students writing $\vec{u}^3$, and what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any orthogonal unit vectors: $$0\neq 1$$
In general to disprove something all you need is one counterexample.

Comment: How do you propose to square a vector, whether or not it is orthogonal to something?

Comment: @Misha By definition the notation $\vec u^2$ means the dot product $\vec u\cdot\vec u$, which is the square of the norm of $\vec u$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I'm not sure if I understand, do you set $\vec{u} = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: By no definition I have ever seen does squaring a vector have that meaning.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I learned that from the first day I heard about vectors. See https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Produit_scalaire_dans_le_plan/Produit_scalaire_de_deux_vecteurs#Carr%C3%A9_scalaire

Comment: This seems incompatible with treating vectors as $n\times 1$ matrices. If you really want your dot products to be multiplication, why not write $\vec u^{\mathsf T} \vec u$ instead? Regardless, ultimately it is up to the author of the question to clarify.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Why would anyone introduce that notation to mean exactly $\lVert u\rVert_2^2$?

Comment: @ClementC. to avoid large amounts of double bars, since there is no conflict with another notation anyway.

Comment: @kathelk no, $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are unit vectors here, so for instance $\left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right)$ and $\left(\matrix{0\\1\\0}\right)$.

Comment: In France (at least) it is a rather common notation. It allows to easily generalize some formulas. And often it causes problem to students to know what they are working with.

Answer (score 2):

To show that a "rule" is wrong, you only need to show that it is wrong *once.*

Let 
$$
\vec{u} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad
\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Work out the values of
$\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle^2$
and
$\vec{u}^2\cdot\vec{v}^2.$
Compare them. If they are not the same, the rule is false.

---

For the calculations, make sure you understand what 
$\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle$ means and what $\vec{u}^2$ means.
In matrix notation, if 
$$
\vec{u} = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad
\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3  \end{pmatrix},
$$
then
$$
\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle =
\begin{pmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3  \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\vec{u}^2 =
\begin{pmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

In other words, 
$\left\langle\vec{u},\vec{v}\right\rangle = \vec u^T \vec v$
when $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are column vectors.